# what i use in place of indexOf in php

Tags: php

here's my code so please tell me what i used in place of indexOf usind php because there is no indexOf function in php  .

```
function generate($arrLength)
{
    $arr = array();
    $n = 0;
    $start = 10;
    $end = 20;
    for($i=0; $i < $arrLength; $i++)
    {
        do{
            $n = $start + round(rand()*($end - $start));
        }while($arr.indexOf($n) !== -1);
        $arr[$i] = $n;
    }
    return $arr;
}
$generatedArr = generate(4);
```

Comment: May I suggest you take a look at the php documentation? That is what it was written for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php  Also, a simple google question would have told you the same.

Comment: array_search for arrays, strpos for strings

Comment: Or just get an overview of the array functions first: http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

Comment: What are you trying to do with this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_search()` in this case:

```
function generate($arrLength) {
    $arr = array();
    $n = 0;
    $start = 10;
    $end = 20;
    for($i=0; $i < $arrLength; $i++) {
        do {
            $n = $start + round(rand()*($end - $start));

        } while(array_search($n, $arr) !== false);
        $arr[$i] = $n;
    }

    return $arr;
}

$generatedArr = generate(4);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($generatedArr);
```